# Let $T:\Bbb{R}^m\to \Bbb{R}^n$ is linear map. Prove that, $T$ is closed map iff $T=0$ or $T$ is injective.

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

Suppose $T$ is injective. Then $T:\Bbb{R}^m\to \text{Ran}(T)$ is bijective, continuous. Then $T^{-1}:\text{Ran}(T)\to \Bbb{R}^m$ is continuous. So, $\exists c>0$ such that $\lVert Tx\rVert\ge c\lVert x\rVert $ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}^m$.

Let $C$ be a closed set in $\Bbb{R}^m$. We've to show $T(C)$ is closed. Let $T(x_n)\in T(C)$ such that $T(x_n)\to y$. In particular, $\{Tx_n\}$ is cauchy, hence $\{x_n\}$ is. There is $x\in\Bbb{R}^m$, $x_n\to x$, this implies $x\in C$ (as $C$ is closed) and $Tx_n\to Tx$, hence $y=Tx\in T(C)$. This proves that $T(C)$ is closed.

Now for the converse part assume $T$ is closed. We have to prove $T=0$ or $T$ is injective. Suppose, $T\ne 0$.

We look at $S=\{x\in\Bbb{R}^m:\ \lVert x\rVert =1\}$. Then $T(S)$ is closed and bounded subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$, hence compact. We claim that $\inf\{\lVert Tx\rVert :\ x\in S\}>0$. Suppose not i.e. $\inf\{\lVert Tx\rVert :\ x\in S\}=0$ As $T(S)$ is compact, this infimum is attained. So, there is $x_0\in S$ such that $T(x_0)=\inf\{\lVert Tx\rVert :\ x\in S\}=0$. I cannot proceed further. Can anyone help me to complete the proof? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose that $T\ne0$ and that $T$ is not injective. Let $W=\ker T$ and take a vector $v\in W^\perp\setminus\{0\}$ (with respect to the standard inner product in $\Bbb R^n$). Since $v\notin W$, $Tv\ne0$. Fix some $w\in W\setminus\{0\}$ and consider the set
$$C=\left\{\frac1nv+nw\,\middle|\,n\in\Bbb N\right\}.$$Then $C$ is a closed set, since, if $n\ne m$,\begin{align}\left\|\frac1nv+nw-\left(\frac1mv+mw\right)\right\|&=\left\|\left(\frac1n-\frac1m\right)v+(n-m)w\right\|\\&=\sqrt{\left(\frac1n-\frac1m\right)^2\|v\|^2+(n-m)^2\|w\|^2}\\&\geqslant\|w\|.\end{align}But$$T(C)=\left\{\frac{T(v)}n\,\middle|\,n\in\Bbb N\right\},$$which is not a closed set, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{T(v)}n=0\notin T(C)$.

Comment: Very nice proof! Professor, how do you construct such beautiful counterexamples?? How do you have such ability to see through the problem??

Comment: @krishna2016 I have a lot of experience. But I must say that this is one of my finest answers.

Comment: Indeed, professor. This answer deserves more upvotes than it already has. I was blown away by your construction and the idea behind it.